# Как пользоваться vk.api?

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я создал приложение на [vk.com/dev](https://vk.com/dev). В настройках указал адрес сайта `http://localhost:8081/`, Базовый домен: `localhost`.
Далее подключил библиотеку [vkapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vkapi) и пробую  авторизироваться:

```js
var vk = new VK({
  'appID'     : 5624111,
  'appSecret' : 'BSXVqQsTSO66GDEF1111',
  'mode'      : 'oauth'
});
```

Но в консоли ошибка:

> Uncaught Error: nodejs-vk-sdk: you have to specify VK application id

Іd и ключ точно правильные. Что я забыл добавить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в написании слова `appID`, поменяйте `appID` на `appId`

Это должно решить вашу проблему.

А ещё вам стоит проверить актуальность версии библиотеки сверившись со страницей библиотеки на [GitHub](https://github.com/57uff3r/nodejs-vksdk)

Вот рабочий код:

```
var VK = require('vksdk');

var vk = new VK({
    'appId'     : 2807970,
    'appSecret' : 'L1ZKpgQPalJdumI6vFK',
    'mode'      : 'sig'
});
```

[Проверить в браузере](https://tonicdev.com/57d4a371da839a14006e6635/57d4a3d820f7ed1400cf1c12)

Comment: Я пробую сделать get запрос и получаю ошибку `https://api.vk.com/method/users.get. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. ... ` Через localhost пробую, в настройках приложения так же localhost указал. Проблема в том, что надо сервер иметь для подобных запросов?

Comment: @Slava, localhost указывает не на ваш компьютер, в настройках приложения укажите адрес вашего компьютера, с которого производится запрос к API.